# Clarification about consequence of physics' first principle of thermodynamics

Tags: limits, physics

I'm reading the book  *Physics, by Tipler*, and I'm confused at the following statement:

> [...] From the first principle of thermodynamics, $\Delta U = Q+ W$. Suppose an ideal gas is given heat while keeping it's volume constant, then $W=0$ and $Q=Q_v:= C_V\Delta T$, where $C_V$ is the heat capacity of the gas, then 
>   $$
> \Delta U = C_V\, \Delta T
> $$
>   **Taking the limit as $\Delta T$ goes to $0$, we get**
>   $$
> d\,U= C_V \, d\, T
> $$

I don't understand that last "equation", taking the limit we should just get $\lim_{\Delta T} U = 0$, and nothing more. I've taken calculus, introductory real analysis, and a few other math courses (I'm a math student) and I still don't understand these famous differentials.

Does the statement in the book make any sense?

Comment: Would it make more sense to you like this? $$\Delta U(\Delta T) = C_V\, \Delta T \\ \implies \frac{\Delta U(\Delta T)}{\Delta T} = C_V \\ \implies \lim_{\Delta T\to 0} \frac{\Delta U(\Delta T)}{\Delta T} = \lim_{\Delta T\to 0} C_V \\ \implies \frac{dU}{dT} = C_V \\ \implies dU = C_VdT$$

Comment: @Bye_World Kind of: I don't see why $C_V \Delta T \not \to 0$. Also, the $\frac {dU}{dT} = C_V \implies d\,U  = C_V\, d\, T$ implication still does not make much sense to me... I understand $\frac {dU}{dT}$ as only another way of writing $U'$...

Comment: Yes, I see that if "multiplying by $d\, x$" were a valid operation, that would be the result, but I've read and heard uncountably many times things like "You can't multiply by $dx$!", "$dx$ is not a number", etc... That's why this doesn't 'feel right'.

Comment: And then what is $d\,x$? (saying $dy/f'$ would be a bit circular...)

Comment: This sort of argument is typical in physics; it can be recast in a more mathematically rigorous form. The real problem is with the equation $\Delta U=C_v\Delta T$. Strictly speaking this is wrong -- indeed, it gets it backwards -- because $C_v$ is really *defined* to be the partial derivative of $U$ with respect to $T$ holding $V$ constant (hence it represents the *infinitesimal* change in $U$ due to infinitesimal changes in $T$, not the *macroscopic* change as the equation $\Delta U=C_v\Delta T$ says). This is not really a derivation so much as a definition.

Comment: (In other words, the *definition* of $C_v$ is $\lim_{\Delta T\to 0}\frac{\Delta U}{\Delta T}$, where $V$ is held constant, and the equation $\Delta U=C_v\Delta T$ is a first-order approximation.)

Comment: @physicsBookIsWrong I really think you shouldn't get hung up on these types of problems. A good chunk of actual physicists do calculations like these with far less rigor, and derive correct results. It's not what a mathematician would do, and it does come up eventually, but one should really take a "when in Rome" approach to reading Physics books. Learning Rigor is important, but learning how to perform Physical reasoning is very important if you want to survive in that land, and learning a large number of view points is important when deciding what field to pursue IMHO.

Comment: @Kamina: I shouldn't have used the word "rigor," which is not really at issue here. You have to be able to reason through a calculation in order to apply it to new problems. If the reasoning isn't sensible, it's impossible to learn how to apply a technique; otherwise you're just shooting in the dark. In this case the book is being dishonest or sloppy. The point is that for small temperature differences we assume the specific heat is basically constant, so we can model the problem with a derivative. In other words we make a 1st order approximation. This could have been more carefully explained.